# remove "()" in Rdata

Tags: r, dplyr, character

There is an example data.

|type |
|1,2()|
|1,3()|
|1    |

I would like to remove "()" in the data.

|type |
|1,2  |
|1,3  |
|1    |

So, I tried the "str_replace" in dplyr package.

```
mutate(type = str_replace(type, pattern="()", replacement =""))
```

But it didn't work, and there is still "()" in the data.
How does it work?

Comment: `()` have special meaning in regex, you need to escape them. Use `str_remove(type, "\\(|\\)")`

Answer (score 0):

```
mutate(type = str_replace_all(type, pattern="[()]", replacement =""))
```